# Sending Email From Silverlight Without Using A Webservice to handle the emailing part

Tags: .net, silverlight

Is this possible? I assume not but would be happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making Silverlight capable of becoming a spamming platform out-of-the-box would be considered "really *really* bad". Thankfully it is not allowed by default :)

You can however now communicate with COM components, so it *is* possible to do pretty much anything (if the COM components are installed). This includes full COM automation of apps (like office apps, including Outlook). You can also write your own COM components but of course they have to be installed independently of Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

If it has elevated privileges you can connect to the recipients SMTP server via TCP - Silverlight comes with a socket API. All you need to implement is a small subset of the SMTP protocol, which is fairly easy. No need for COM and works also in Silverlight 3.